# Show 404 instead of 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cgi-bin, errordocument

I'm trying to show 404 error instead of 403 and I have been able to do that with the following line:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
```

but it wasn't applied to /cgi-bin

Please guide me to the reason that it is not applied on cgi-bin and how to show 404 instead of 403 for this path.

Thank you and I apologize for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the lines below to your cgi script configuration:

```
RewriteCond !%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} "=403"
RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/404.html [L]
```